# How can I implement the following SQL query as linq to entities query?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-entities

How can I implement the following SQL query as linq to entities query?

```
select *, MIN(QueuedDate)
from pcm_transactions
where QueuedDate IS NOT NULL And ExecutionDate IS NULL
group by SimId
```

I spent hours thinking and trying varius methods - hope to find the right answer here.

**EDIT:**

Here is one of my first tries:

```
//  Get the oldest queued action
var queuedTransactions =
    (from t in db.TransactionSet
        where t.QueuedDate.HasValue && !t.ExecutionDate.HasValue
        group t by new { t.TransactionId, t.QueuedDate } into tr
        select new
        {
            Transaction = db.TransactionSet.First(q => q.TransactionId == tr.Key.TransactionId), 
            QueuedDate = tr.Min(m => m.QueuedDate)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: One problem is that the SQL isn't valid to start with; You have to group by every column that is not an aggregate expression (eg. min/max etc), so "select *" simply doesn't make sense.  Do you have sample data and required results to help us rewrite this into Linq?

Comment: OK, but I need the whole row - not just the minimal QueuedDate - how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One problem is that the SQL isn't valid to start with; You have to
>   group by every column that is not an aggregate expression (eg. min/max
>   etc), so "select *" simply doesn't make sense. Do you have sample data
>   and required results to help us rewrite this into Linq?

– Quoted from Will's comment